# Skipping lines using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, file-processing

I'm trying to skip the first 2 lines (from reading 3 files) then save back (I already got this done, all that's left is the line skipping)

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way of doing it. Perhaps it's a bit overkill, as it's not very efficient. (using `file()` would be much faster)

```
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$skipped_content = implode("\n", array_slice($lines, 2));
```

Comment: I chose this answer since I don't really have to rewrite any code and it works great =)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but using file_get_contents it would be too complicated. I advise using the `file()` function instead:

```
$file_array = file("yourfile.txt");
unset($file_array[0]);
unset($file_array[1]);
file_put_contents("outfile.txt", implode("", $file_array));
```

Comment: file() will load the whole file into memory, just wanted to mention this. I would go with fopen() and reading the file manually in chunks seeking for newline characters or just use strpos($content, "\n") and cut this part of the string. :)

Comment: @ludesign: Valid point, thanks. You can post your answer with a sample code :)

Answer (score 0):

use file(), then unset the the first 2 array keys then  implode

Answer (score 0):

If lines are not very long can't you just use regex on read files? From php manual there is offset parameter in file_get_contents, though this most likely wont be useful since then you need to know line lengths in advance. Maybe file_get_contents isn't proper function to use in this case?